# How to get the pure file path from tkinter's filedialog.askopenfile()?

Tags: python, tkinter, path

I'm using `sourceDir = filedialog.askopenfile()` to get a file's path, so when I choose the file and print its path, I want to get `D:/GitHub/repo/test.jpg`, but instead I'm getting `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='D:/GitHub/repo/test.jpg' mode='r' encoding='cp1250'>`. How can I print only the "name"?

Here's a simplified version of my whole code

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import filedialog

sourceDir = ""

sourceDir = filedialog.askopenfile()
print(f"source file: {sourceDir}")
input("")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code `sourceDir = filedialog.askopenfile()` that was posted in the original question, the filename can be accessed via `sourceDir.name`.

Alternatively, the `tkinter.filedialog` module has an `askopenfilename` function. This function will only return the filename string.

```
sourceDir = filedialog.askopenfilename()
print(f"source file: {sourceDir}")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **sourceDir.name**

which will give you the "D:/GitHub/repo/test.jpg"

sourceDir = filedialog.askopenfile()
print(f"source file: {sourceDir.name}")